# Conditional format to shade rows if value or date is found?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, vba

I am new to conditional formatting and trying to create a few functions that will work in Excel 2010.

First I am trying to grey out (or shade) all rows that contain a value less than or equal to `35` in column E.

Second I need to BOLD all rows that contain today or tomorrow's date in column G. It would be nice to exclude weekends. For example if today is Friday it would bold all columns with Friday and Monday in it.

I have not been been able to get either to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the weekends, please try:

```
=$E1<=35
```

with grey fill and

```
=OR($G1=INT(NOW()),$G1=INT(NOW())+1)
```

with bold, each with Applies to:

```
=$A$1:$Z$100
```

Extend/adjust the Applies to: range to suit.

and to skip weekends (in place of the second formula above):

```
=AND($G1>=INT(NOW()),$G1<INT(NOW())+10-NETWORKDAYS($G1,$G1+7))
```

---

*Edit re comment of 2013-08-16 14:00:28Z*:

This is getting VERY messy but keeping the latest requirement as a separate condition (also bold) perhaps adding another formula (in any order as Stop If True should not be checked) would suit:

```
=AND(OR($G1=INT(NOW()),$G1=INT(NOW())+3),MOD(TODAY(),7)=6)
```

This will not embolden Sundays between emboldened Saturdays and Mondays.

(Based on Excel 2007 and UNTESTED)

Comment: Excellent!  That worked.  Is there any way I can BOLD anything that is from tomorrow OR older?  Meaning if something is from two weeks ago it will also be bolded.

Comment: I need to bold anything that is due today or tomorrow, or anything that is past due.  That means anything from today, tomorrow, and the past must be bolded.

Comment: What I'm hoping to see is if today is Friday then it will see something due Monday and still mark it bold even though it is actually due more than one day ahead.

Comment: To add to that I guess it would be something like this:

Comment: =OR($G1=INT(NOW()),$G1=INT(NOW())+1) UNLESS TODAY IS FRIDAY THEN Now())+3)